# How can I install 'Revenge of the Titans'?

Tags: installation, software-center, games, dpkg

Revenge of the Titans is one of the games from the [Humble Indie Bundle](http://www.humblebundle.com/). I downloaded the i386 .deb file (I'm on a 32bit installation) and tried to install it using the Software Centre. However, when it was nearly finished I got this error:

[image: Installation Error]

I then tried to install it using `dpkg` and it failed to install, giving the following error:

```
dpkg: error processing RevengeOfTheTitans-HIB-i386.deb (--install):
unable to create `/opt/revengeofthetitans/full_length_music/einleitung.mp3.dpkg-new' (while processing
 `/opt/revengeofthetitans/full_length_music/einleitung.mp3'): No such file or directory
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try running this command first:

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/revengeofthetitans/full_length_music
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution on Ubuntu forums

sudo mkdir -p /opt/revengeofthetitans/full_length_music

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1644127