# How do I install Revenge of the Titans?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook

I've downloaded the `.deb` file of Revenge of the Titans, and installed it using Ubuntu Software Center.

Now, when I try to launch it using the software launcher nothing happens.
Any ideas?

The `.deb` file was downloaded from the Humble Indie Bundle.

I am unable to launch it from the terminal  ( the command `revenge-of-the-titans` says command not found ).

I also tried the `.tar.gz.` When I extract it and run `./revenge.sh` , nothing happens. No output on the terminal or anything at all.

I have set `chmod 777 revenge.sh` as well.

The command `/opt/revengeofthetitans/revenge.sh`  does not give any output.

If I run `gedit /opt/revengeofthetitans/revenge.sh` in the terminal:

```
> #!/bin/bash
> #
> # revenge.sh
> #
> ###############################################################################
> 
> SCRIPT="`basename $0`"
> GAMEDIR="${HOME}/.revenge_of_the_titans_1.80" LOGFILE="${GAMEDIR}/${SCRIPT}.log"
> INSTDIR="`dirname $0`" ; cd
> "${INSTDIR}" ; INSTDIR="`pwd`"
> 
> [[ ! -d "${GAMEDIR}" ]] && mkdir -m
> 0755 "${GAMEDIR}"
> 
> JARPATH="patch.jar:RevengeOfTheTitans.jar:data-hib.jar:gfx.jar:fonts.jar:images.jar:music.jar:fx-mono.jar:fx-stereo.jar:gamecommerce.jar:common.jar:spgl-lite.jar:lwjgl.jar:lwjgl_util.jar:jorbis.jar:jinput.jar"
> 
> # XMODIFIERS is cleared here to prevent SCIM screwing up keyboard
> input XMODIFIERS= java \
>     -noverify \
>     -Djava.library.path="${INSTDIR}" \
>     -Dorg.lwjgl.util.NoChecks=true \
>     -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath="${INSTDIR}" \
>     -Dnet.puppygames.applet.Launcher.resources=/resources-hib.dat
> \
>     -Dnet.puppygames.applet.Game.gameResource=game.hib
> \
>     -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=3 \
>     -Xms64m \
>     -Xmx375m \
>     -Xincgc \
>     -cp "${JARPATH}" \
>     net.puppygames.applet.Launcher \
>     "$@" \
>     >"${LOGFILE}" 2>&1
> 
> exit 0
> 
> #
> # EOF
> #
> ###############################################################################
```

Comment: please edit your question with the link to this "deb".  Also, what happens when you launch the software from a terminal session - any errors displayed?

Comment: Please add the output uf the command ''/opt/revengeofthetitans/revenge.sh''

Comment: what is the name of the deb file? I just downloaded and installed RevengeOfTheTitans-HIB-1811-i386.deb, I think they do update the links on the humble page, as the last file I downloaded did not have 1811 in the name... maybe try downloading again. Also check cat ~/.revenge_of_the_titans_1.80/revenge.sh.log

Comment: @sBlatt  Filename is RevengeOfTheTitans-HIB-1811-i386.deb

Comment: @fossfreedom @sBlatt  Have updated the original post accordingly

Comment: The game appears to write to a log file - what's the contents of the logfile - ~/.revenge_of_the_titans_1.80/revenge.log (or something like that) - also please edit your question to have the revenge.sh surrounded by a Code Sample Tag (this will aid readability)

Comment: The log file doesnt seem to exist  akash@akash-laptop:~$ ~/.revenge_of_the_titans_1.80/revenge.log
bash: /home/akash/.revenge_of_the_titans_1.80/revenge.log: No such file or directory

Comment: This could be a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/17425/how-can-i-install-revenge-of-the-titans

Comment: The install process succeeds, so I dont think its a duplicate of that issue, still I'll try the steps mentioned there and reply

Comment: The music folder already exists, so its not a duplicate. Basically the issue seems to be that the revenge.sh file does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

Reinstalling openJDK from the Ubuntu software center fixed it